# Python multiprocessing shared memory; one write, multiple read

Tags: python, arrays, multiprocessing, pipe, shared-memory

**SYSTEM**

- Linux (Manjaro KDE)
- Python 3.8.3

**PROGRAM:**
I have incoming string data on a UDP port. The main loop spools up the processes prior to using selectors to monitor the UDP port. I want the UDP data, which is constantly updated, available for each process.

**TRIED:**

- Multiprocessing Queues with maxsize = 1 and that became a headache and quickly broke down.
- Multiprocessing Arrays (this is where I'm at now)

I have checked, and the Array at each location I'm looking at has the same memory address (I think). For whatever reason, when I try to access the contents of the Array in the child process, the process hangs.

**NOT TRIED**

- Pipes. I have a feeling this may be the way to go. But I'm already deep in uncharted territory; I've never used them before.

**WHAT I WANT**
I would like to access the UDP data from the child processes - these are the camera_view method.

**Dummy UDP string**

```
import socket
import random
import datetime
import time

conn = ('127.0.0.1', 6666)

def rand_value(f_val, t_val):
    result = round(random.uniform(f_val, t_val), 2)  
    result = random.uniform(f_val, t_val)
    return result

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

while True:

    time.sleep(6)
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    overlay = timestamp

    for i in range(9):
        val = rand_value(i*10, i*10+10)
        if i == 8: val = 'TASK: Im the real Batman'
        overlay = overlay + "," + str(val)
    
    print(overlay)
    sock.sendto(overlay.encode(), conn)
```

**My Program**

```
import datetime
import selectors
import socket
import time
from multiprocessing import Lock, Process, Queue
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import Array
from ctypes import c_char_p


REQUIRED_CAMERAS = 1
CAMERA_CONN = {'name':['Colour Camera'], 'ip':['127.0.0.1'], 'port':[9000]}
OVERLAY_CONN = ('0.0.0.0', 6666)
CONTROL_CONN = ('0.0.0.0', 6667)
NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_IN_OVERLAY = 10

class Camera():
    def __init__(self, cam_name, cam_ip, cam_port):
        self.ip = cam_ip
        self.port = cam_port
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.frame_width = int(self.capture.get(3))
        self.frame_height = int(self.capture.get(4))
        self.name = cam_name


def get_overlay(data_packet):
        data = data_packet.decode()
        data = data.split(',')
        field0 = data[0]
        field1 = 'KP: ' + str(round(float(data[1]), 3))
        field2 = 'DCC: ' + str(round(float(data[2]), 2)) + 'm'
        field3 = 'E: ' + str(round(float(data[3]), 2)) + 'm'
        field4 = 'N: ' + str(round(float(data[4]), 2)) + 'm'
        field5 = 'D: ' + str(round(float(data[5]), 2)) + 'm'
        field6 = 'H: ' + str(round(float(data[6]), 2)) # + '°'
        field7 = 'R: ' + str(round(float(data[7]), 2)) # + '°'
        field8 = 'P: ' + str(round(float(data[8]), 2)) # + '°' 
        field9 = data[9]

        x = []
        for i in range(NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_IN_OVERLAY):
            x.append(eval('field' + str(i)).encode())
            # if i == 0:
            #     print(x[i])
                
        return x

def socket_reader(sock, mask, q, REQUIRED_CAMERAS, overlay):
    data_packet, sensor_ip = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    sensor_port = sock.getsockname()[1]
    print(f'SENSOR PORT {sensor_port} and SENSOR_IP {sensor_ip}')

    if sensor_port == OVERLAY_CONN[1]:
        x = get_overlay(data_packet)
        for i in range(len(x)):
            overlay[i] = x[i]
            print(f'Socket Reader {overlay}')

def camera_view(CAMERA_CONN, cam_name, camera, overlay_q, control_q, overlay):
    while True:
        print(f'PROCESS {camera} RUNNING FOR: {cam_name}')
        try:
            print(f'Camera View {overlay}')
            for i in range(len(overlay)):
                print(overlay[i])
        except:
            pass
        time.sleep(1)
        

def controller(REQUIRED_CAMERAS, CAMERA_CONN, OVERLAY_CONN, CONTROL_CONN):
    
    if REQUIRED_CAMERAS > len(CAMERA_CONN['name']):
        print(f'REQURIED_CAMERAS: {REQUIRED_CAMERAS} - more than connections in CAMERA_CONN ')
    else:
        # Set up a UDP connection for the overlay string and the control commands
        sock_overlay = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        sock_control = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        sock_overlay.bind(OVERLAY_CONN)
        sock_control.bind(CONTROL_CONN)
        
        # Set up the selector to watch over the socket
        # and trigger when data is ready for reading
        sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()
        sel.register(fileobj=sock_overlay, events=selectors.EVENT_READ, data=socket_reader)
        sel.register(fileobj=sock_control, events=selectors.EVENT_READ, data=socket_reader)
        
        # create shared memory
        overlay_q = Queue(maxsize=1)
        control_q = Queue(maxsize=1)     
        overlay = Array(c_char_p, range(NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_IN_OVERLAY))
        print(f'Init Overlay {overlay}')
        
        # Generate the processes; one per camera
        processes = []
        
        for camera in range(REQUIRED_CAMERAS):
            processes.append(Process(target=camera_view, args=(CAMERA_CONN, CAMERA_CONN['name'][camera], camera, overlay_q, control_q, overlay)))

        for process in processes:
            process.daemon = True
            process.start()
            
        # Spin over the selector
        while True:

            # Only have one connnection registered, so to stop
            # the loop spinning up the CPU, I have made it blocking 
            # with the timeout = 1 (sec) instead of =0.
            events = sel.select(timeout=None)

            for key, mask in events:
                # the selector callback is the data= from the register above
                callback = key.data
                # the callback gets the sock, mask and the sensor queues
                if key.fileobj == sock_overlay:
                    callback(key.fileobj, mask, overlay_q, REQUIRED_CAMERAS, overlay)
                else:
                    callback(key.fileobj, mask, control_q, REQUIRED_CAMERAS, overlay)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    controller(REQUIRED_CAMERAS, CAMERA_CONN, OVERLAY_CONN, CONTROL_CONN)
```

**EDIT1:**

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Array
from ctypes import c_char_p
import time

def worker(arr):
    count = 0
    while True:
        count += 1
        val = 'val' + str(count)
        arr[0] = val
        print(arr[:])
        time.sleep(2)

def main():
    arr = Array(c_char_p, 1)
    p = Process(target=worker, args=(arr,))
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()
    
    while True:
        print(arr[:])
        try:
            print(arr[:].decode('utf-8'))
        except :
            pass
        # try:
        #     val = arr[:]
        #     val = val.decode('utf-8')
        #     print(f'main {val}')
        # except:
        #     pass
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    
    
'''
from multiprocessing import Process, Array
from ctypes import c_char_p
import time

def worker(arr):
    count = 0
    while True:
        count += 1
        val = 'val' + str(count)
        arr[0] = bytes(val, 'utf-8')
        print(arr[:])
        time.sleep(2)

def main():
    arr = Array(c_char_p, 1)
    p = Process(target=worker, args=(arr,))
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()
    
    while True:
        print(arr[:])
        try:
            print(arr[:].decode('utf-8'))
        except :
            pass

        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
'''
```

**EDIT2:**
Thanks to @RolandSmith, I have persevered with Queues and I think I have got a template on how I can move forward. See below code. If I can't get this to work in program, I'll be back here.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time
import datetime

def worker(camera, q):
    val = ''
    while True:    
        if q.full() == True:
            val = q.get()
        else:
            val = val
        print(f'WORKER{camera} {val}')
        time.sleep(0.2)

def main():
    
    cameras = 2
    
    processes = []
    queues = []
    
    for camera in range(cameras):
        queues.append(Queue(maxsize=1))
        processes.append(Process(target=worker, args=(camera, queues[camera])))
        
    for process in processes:                     
        process.daemon = True
        process.start()

    while True:
        for q in queues:
            if not q.empty():
                try:
                    _ = q.get()
                except:
                    pass
            else:
                q.put(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
        time.sleep(.5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: To start with, props for submitting system information. Lots of people forget to do that. Now on to my comments. As submitted, your program is halfway between a real program and a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which makes it confusing.  Can you clean it up a bit and remove the unused parts? Now onto the problem with the `Queue`s. What do you mean with "that became a headache and quickly broke down"?

Comment: Looking at `get_overlay`, why not make `field` into an array directly, instead of using `eval`?

Comment: @RolandSmith, thanks for replying. I have added an edit. The commented out block works, but it just outputs "test" as typed in to the script. I get None (blank) when I try and program a string.

Comment: @RolandSmith. The issue I had with the queues was passing them around properly along with the locks. The consumer would be reading far faster than the producer and I wanted the consumer to continue to use old data until new data became available.

Comment: Whenever you `get` something from a `Queue` it is gone from the `Queue`. So in the worker, you'd have to use `Queue.empty()`. If that returns `True`, then re-use the previously retrieved data.

Comment: Looking in to converting to c_char_p; will keep searching down that path. I feel like it is the wrong one. Would the ```Queue``` be the way to go - instead of the ```Array```? Or is there some other means to do what I want to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219391/discussion-between-roland-smith-and-mcrae).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my view, using `Queue` is a less error-prone solution than using an `Array`.

Here is your second example, converted to using a `Queue`:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time


def worker(q):
    count = 0 
    while True:
        count += 1
        val = 'val' + str(count)
        q.put(val)
        print('worker:', val)
        time.sleep(2)


def main():
    q = Queue()

    p = Process(target=worker, args=(q, ))
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()

    while True:
        if not q.empty():
            print('main:', q.get())
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This yields:

```
> python3 test3.py
worker: val1
main: val1
worker: val2
main: val2
worker: val3
main: val3
worker: val4
main: val4
worker: val5
```

---

Here is the same example using a `Pipe`:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import time


def worker(p):
    count = 0 
    while True:
        count += 1
        val = 'val' + str(count)
        p.send(val)
        print('worker:', val)
        time.sleep(2)


def main():
    child, parent = Pipe()

    p = Process(target=worker, args=(child, ))
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()

    while True:
        if parent.poll():
            print('main:', parent.recv())
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This produces the same result as the previous example.

Additionally, by default a pipe is bidirectional.
So you could also send back data from the workers to the parent.

Comment: Good man. I started looking in to that Array and found that I needed a = c_**w**char_p as I must have found examples in Py2. Thanks to your input, I will head down the ```Queue``` path again. The reason I didn't was that I had multiple workers that I wanted to use the same data. This would mean the queue.put would be in the main and the q.get would be in the worker. If I had 4x workers, would simply repeating the q.put 4x work or would there be a chance that one worker may slow down and miss out? I guess I'll have to create a q for each worker.

Comment: You would indeed have to create a Queue (or `Pipe`) for each worker to get the data *reliably* to each worker. Keep in mind that a `Queue` is just a `Pipe` with additional locks and semaphores. So you could also use a `Pipe`, see my second example. And since a pipe is bidirectional by default, you could also use that to send messages back from the workers to the parent.